# Trigger keyframes with click function in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to create a rock paper scissors game with UI using html, css and JS and I got stuck on a problem, whenever the user chooses the rock by clicking the rock button, the rock div that contains the image with a fist should start to move on the screen but in my case it doesn't do anything.

The html:

```
<div class="game-screen-elements">
            <h2 class="choice">Make your choice</h2>
            <div class="fist-container">
                <div class="fist-left"></div>
                <div class="fist-right"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="pick">
                <button class="rock" onclick="click()">rock</button>
                <button class="paper">paper</button>
                <button class="scissor">scissors</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The css:

```
.fist-container{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.fist-right, .fist-left{
    background-image: url(assets/rock.png);
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-size: cover;
    
}

.fist-left{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


@keyframes fistLeft {
    0% {
      transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(0px);
    }
    15% {
      transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(-50px);
    }
   /*25% {
      transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(0px);
    } */
    35% {
      transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(-50px);
    }
    50% {
      transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(0px);
    }
    65% {
      transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(-50px);
    }
    75% {
      transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(0px);
    }
    85% {
      transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(-50px);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotateY(180deg) translateY(0px);
    }
  }
  
  @keyframes fistRight {
    0% {
      transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    15% {
      transform: translateY(-50px);
    }
    /*25% {
      transform: translateY(0px);
    } */
    35% {
      transform: translateY(-50px);
    }
    50% {
      transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    65% {
      transform: translateY(-50px);
    }
    75% {
      transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    85% {
      transform: translateY(-50px);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateY(0px);
    }
  }
```

The JS:

```
const playerHand = document.querySelector('.fist-left');
const rockChoice = document.querySelector('rock');
click = function(){
    rockChoice.addEventListener('click', function(){
        playerHand.style.animation = 'fistLeft 2s ease';
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your working Javascript code:

```
const playerHand = document.querySelector('.fist-left');
const rockChoice = document.querySelector('.rock');

rockChoice.addEventListener('click', click);
        

function click(){
    playerHand.style.animation = 'fistLeft 2s ease';
}
```

**Explanation:** What your **click** function does is simply registering the event-listener and not necessarily executing the animation code, hence the event is not triggered. The separated **click** function now actually runs the code responsible for animation since it has been registered for any click events on your element with **.rock** class. Also make sure you are placing the JS code at the bottom of the body tag(inside closing body tag) if you are using it as external script.